# Getting a rule name in the 'when' clause:Drools

Tags: java, drools

How do I get the rulename in the when/Lhs clause of Drools?

Comment: Could you please explain to us why you'd need it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My rulename has a unique 'id' attached to it. I am using this 'id' to make sure that the rule only fires once for a given user [I have a table which maintains a list of rules fired for a given user]. If this particular 'userId' and 'Id' are present in the database,the rule won't be evaluated. Does the approach hold any water ? Is there an alternate approach? Open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach the id to the name of the rule, use a class where you define all rule ids of interest as constants and use those constants, this way you can also very easily track where you reference all these ids.

```
rule "MyRule"
    when
        eval((com.test.Rules.RULE1_ID) == 123)
    then
        ...
end
```

Alternatively, if you have just a few rules, you can use flags part of `User` to indicate whether a rule has been executed for the respective user or not, and then your check would look like `User(!myRuleHasRun)`.

Comment: thanks again :) Will this approach make sure that the rule is fired only once? Pardon the question, but I don't quite seem to grasp the above mentioned concept :) My rules are not static and i use a DSL as well to map the rules. All the rule names are generated on the basis of the clauses it contains[requirement]. Again thanks for your interest in helping me solve the problem :) Am I missing something??

Comment: The first approach solves your problem with getting the id of the executing rule, you still have to do your check just like before. The second approach solves your problem altogether, that's the check that needs to be done. Per default the flag has to be `false`, when the rule has fired it has to be updated to `true` and obviously persisted. It's hard for us to point exactly what needs to be done since I don't know all the specifics. Are you sure you want non-static rules? Why do you need them to be non-static? Questions that have nothing to do with the initial topic, but you must think about.

Comment: I do need them to be dynamic. They are a part of the requirements.I'll try out what you said and keep you posted on the same. thank you for your interest :) Much appreciated!